# How to reflect the change of `max_sync_workers_per_subscription` during replication

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I've changed the parameter `max_sync_workers_per_subscription` in Amazon RDS Postgresql and verified that it changed in the master database:

```
db=> show max_sync_workers_per_subscription;
 max_sync_workers_per_subscription 
-----------------------------------
 2
(1 row)
db=> show max_sync_workers_per_subscription;
 max_sync_workers_per_subscription 
-----------------------------------
 4
(1 row)
```

The problem is that the replication is still using the old `2` value as can been by the CPU usage still only using 2 cores for each logical replication worker, meaning the setting was applied to the subscription.

Below are some relevant settings in the replica:

```
db=# show max_worker_processes;
 max_worker_processes 
----------------------
 8
(1 row)

db=# show max_logical_replication_workers;
 max_logical_replication_workers 
---------------------------------
 4
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `max_sync_workers_per_subscription` and `max_logical_replication_workers` are only relevant on the subscriber, as [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-replication.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-REPLICATION-SUBSCRIBER) says:

> These settings control the behavior of a logical replication subscriber. Their values on the publisher are irrelevant.

Note also that both values cannot exceed the limit set by `max_worker_processes`. To be on the safe side, disable and enable the subscription.